# Downloading Files in Bulk

Tags: linux, plugins, download, midi, bulk

I was wondering if it is possible to download all the files from one page with a plugin or some other method. For instance, if I go to a site that has thousands of MIDI files, is there a way for me to automate it where I download them all in to one folder without having to go in and download each one individually?

Comment: It might be possible with `wget`.

Comment: Yeah, code something for that ? Please head towards the [ask] page and take the [tour], this isn't the p^lace to ask such wuestions, this is way too broad. You don't even have a defined langage. This is not a project it's not even a mature idea.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Why can't I play the MIDI files I have downloaded programmatically, but I can play them when I download them manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50636524/11654)